# How can I change a List method to an Array method?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to use a merge-sort algorithm to sort an Array of numbers, but the algorithm takes in a List<> not an Array[]

I've tried changing the algorithm to use an Array[] instead by replacing '.Count' with '.Length', but because of the fixed-size nature of Arrays I'm having trouble with the lines that use 'add' and 'remove'

```
private static List<int> MergeSort(List<int> unsorted)
        {
            if (unsorted.Count <= 1)
                return unsorted;

            List<int> left = new List<int>();
            List<int> right = new List<int>();

            int middle = unsorted.Count / 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < middle; i++)  
            {
                left.Add(unsorted[i]);
            }
            for (int i = middle; i < unsorted.Count; i++)
            {
                right.Add(unsorted[i]);
            }

            left = MergeSort(left);
            right = MergeSort(right);
            return Merge(left, right);
        }

        private static List<int> Merge(List<int> left, List<int> right)
        {
            List<int> result = new List<int>();

            while (left.Count > 0 || right.Count > 0)
            {
                if (left.Count > 0 && right.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (left.First() <= right.First())  
                    {
                        result.Add(left.First());
                        left.Remove(left.First());      
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result.Add(right.First());
                        right.Remove(right.First());
                    }
                }
                else if (left.Count > 0)
                {
                    result.Add(left.First());
                    left.Remove(left.First());
                }
                else if (right.Count > 0)
                {
                    result.Add(right.First());

                    right.Remove(right.First());
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

I would like to be able to pass an unsorted array into the method and it output a sorted array.

Comment: You can't `Add` and `Remove` to an array. An array based solution won't involve adding and removing - it will involve using `Array.Copy` to copy subsets of the array back to different locations within the same array. The implementation will be quite different. Alternatively, take an array as a parameter and `ToList` it. Then keep the logic as is, and then `ToArray` right at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays are fixed sized and do not share the same methods as Lists, which are variable sized. Thus you need to convert your Array to a List then pass the List as the param to the method. You can use:

```
List<object> list = myArray.Cast<Object>().ToList();
```

Or if you prefer linq:

```
List<object> list = myArray.ToList<object>();
```